# How to make line segments transparent based on value using seaborn in python

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

I am using the following example code presented by user "dnswlt" for creating a multiple lineplot using seaborn in python:

```
num_rows = 20
years = list(range(1990, 1990 + num_rows))
data_preproc = pd.DataFrame({
    'Year': years, 
    'A': np.random.randn(num_rows).cumsum(),
    'B': np.random.randn(num_rows).cumsum(),
    'C': np.random.randn(num_rows).cumsum(),
    'D': np.random.randn(num_rows).cumsum()})

sns.lineplot(x='Year', y='value', hue='variable', 
             data=pd.melt(data_preproc, ['Year']))
```

This produces the following multiple lineplot, with a different colored solid line for each category:
[image]

What I am trying to do is to make each value in the lineplot transparent based on whether it falls outside of a range of -2 to 2, with the colors preserved. For example, if the red D line, ever falls outside of this range, this line would turn to a transparent pink. Is there a simple and straightforward way to accomplish this using seaborn, such as a specific conditional styling argument?

Comment: "*Is there a simple and straightforward way to accomplish this using seaborn, such as a specific conditional styling argument?*" -> No, you have to manually split the data

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct functionality in which to specify the lineplot transparency, based on a condition within Seaborn. In order to acheive this transparency effect we can use a mask for values outside the range.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

num_rows = 20
years = list(range(1990, 1990 + num_rows))
data_preproc = pd.DataFrame({
    'Year': years, 
    'A': np.random.randn(num_rows).cumsum(),
    'B': np.random.randn(num_rows).cumsum(),
    'C': np.random.randn(num_rows).cumsum(),
    'D': np.random.randn(num_rows).cumsum()})

# Melt the data to long format
melted_data = pd.melt(data_preproc, id_vars=['Year'], var_name='variable', value_name='value')

# Mask values that fall outside the range [-2, 2]
mask = (melted_data['value'] < -2) | (melted_data['value'] > 2)

# Create the figure and axis
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Plot lines with mask applied
sns.lineplot(x='Year', y='value', hue='variable', data=melted_data, ax=ax, palette="husl")
sns.lineplot(x='Year', y='value', hue='variable', data=melted_data[mask], ax=ax, palette="husl", linestyle='dashed', alpha=0.3)

# Display plot
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tested the code? This will overlay incorrect connection lines on top of the masked values

Comment: correct. using pointplot instead of lineplot when dealing with masked values will avoid connecting lines between the masked and unmasked data points.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to do this with `seaborn`, you can however mask the values outside the range and plot them twice.

Note that you need to use a [`pointplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pointplot.html) as `lineplot` would incorrectly connect the values before and after the masked ones.

```
tmp = data_preproc.melt('Year')

ax = sns.pointplot(x='Year', y='value', hue='variable',
                   marker='', legend=False,
                   data=tmp, alpha=0.3)

sns.pointplot(x='Year', y='value', hue='variable',
              marker='', ax=ax,
              data=tmp.assign(value=tmp['value'].where(tmp['value'].between(-2, 2))))
```

Output:

[image: Seaborn line mask region below above threshold]
*Note that the cutting point is not exactly on the -2/2 horizontal line but rather on the exact values of the points before/after the masked points.*

---

Another option is to plot as you did and to overlay a transparent white patch to mimic a change of intensity. The advantage is that the cutting point will be exactly on the expected threshold, and you can also easily use an arbitrary function as threshold, not just a fixed value:

```
ax = sns.lineplot(x='Year', y='value', hue='variable',
                  zorder=0,
                  data=data_preproc.melt('Year'))

MIN, MAX = ax.get_ylim()
low, high = -2, 2

ax.fill_between(data_preproc['Year'].agg(['min', 'max']),
                [high]*2, [MAX]*2,
                color='w', alpha=0.7, zorder=1)

ax.fill_between(data_preproc['Year'].agg(['min', 'max']),
                [MIN]*2, [low]*2,
                color='w', alpha=0.7, zorder=1)
```

Output:

[image: matplotlib mask region below above threshold]

In fact this is really something like:

[image: matplotlib mask region below above threshold trick revealed]